# What is the right approach in this kind of broadcast?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

So,what is the right approach in this broadcasting ?
I have used a for loop to verify my broadcasting output.
As you can see, it missed to broadcast the second element.
Any idea on this?

```
from numpy import sum
from imageio import imread
import numpy as np
#https://github.com/glennford49/sampleImages/blob/main/cat1.png
#https://github.com/glennford49/sampleImages/blob/main/cat2.png
img1="cat1.png"
img2="cat2.png"
imageDict={}
img1=imread(img1)
img2=imread(img2)
imageDict["images1"]= (1,img1)
imageDict["images2"]=(2,img2)
listdict= list(map(lambda x:x[1], imageDict.values()))
diff= np.array(np.array(img2-listdict))
result = np.sum(diff,axis=1)/img2.size       
result = sum(result)
print("diff per pixel:",(result))
for item in diff: # verifier
    res=item / np.array(img2.size) 
    res = sum(abs(res.reshape(-1)))
    print("loop difference:",res)
```

prints:

```
diff per  pixel: 57.400979382804046 
loop difference: 57.40097938280404
loop difference: 0.0
```

target :

```
diff per  pixel: 57.400979382804046 , 0.0
loop difference: 57.40097938280404
loop difference: 0.0
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible input?

Comment: That's a working code, the 2 images can be downloded in a github page,  I 've spended days of  this problem, help is really appreciated.

Comment: The 2 images that are on GitHub have different shapes.  (275, 184, 3) and (276, 183, 3). How do you plan to broadcast and calculate differences?

Comment: But mine have same shapes both are (276,183,3)

Comment: Thats why I said, please provide reproducable inputs. When i physically go and download the 2 images from github, i get different shapes.

Comment: Im sorry for that.. I have uploaded same shape of two images.

Comment: Check my answer. let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `np.stack` the images instead of the `dict` and `list`. This gives you a (2, 276, 183, 3) tensor. which is broadcastable with (276, 183, 3).

Second, In the last `sum` you need to avoid using `sum` and instead use `np.sum(axis=(1,2))`. This will leave the axis=0 from being summed and give you the 2 difference values you are looking for.

```
import numpy as np

#Replace with your cat images
img1=np.random.random((276, 183, 3))
img2=np.random.random((276, 183, 3))

imageDict["images1"]= (1,img1)
imageDict["images2"]=(2,img2)
listdict = list(map(lambda x:x[1], imageDict.values()))

diff = img2 - listdict
result = np.sum(diff, axis=1)/img2.size
result = np.sum(result, axis=(1,2))
result
```

```
array([0.00016465, 0.        ])
```

Comment: If I use a dict or list to hold my images ,does it mean it cannot be broadcasted in any means? Your code works as expected and give me the exact target output, however I have to use dictionary because image data will not be only 2, it can go up to higher numbers, Anyway thanks for your idea.

Comment: Yes you can, Updated it. You jsut have to pass the `listdict` to instead of `np.stack`. The sum over `axis(1,2)` is the main change you need.

Comment: Let me know if that solves your question.

Comment: thank you for this axis=(1,2), scratching my head all because of this. Works like a charm.